# html JavaScript onunload

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am using the JavaScript method `onunload`, but this is triggered when the page is close or navigated to another page or the back button is hit. Is there a way to differentiate between page closing and the back button being hit? I am using a combination of html JavaScript and PHP as the server side language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to differentiate between these. If you use `onbeforeunload` as Gidon suggested, you can at least offer the user the choice whether he wants to stay on the current page or really leave and possibly lose data.

**UPDATE**: if you are playing around with iframes, it **might** be possible (though not surely cross-browser), found it here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1590281&page=25

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload